# Ruby Escape Backslash For Sed Command

Tags: ruby

I have a `sed` command:

```
sed "\#/,#d" /tmp/dest_sorted
```

I need to run this command in my Ruby script. I've tried this:

```
sed_command = "sed '\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"
p sed_command
```

I get the following result:

```
"sed '#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"
```

I've tried adding a second backslash:

```
sed_command = "sed '\\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"
```

but I get this:

```
"sed '\\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"
```

How can I preserve the single backslash at the beginning of my `sed` command?

Comment: If you do `puts sed_command` instead of `p sed_command` you'll see that escaping the backslash [worked exactly as intended](https://repl.it/@jrunning/TidyImperfectExams).

Answer (score 2):

You can use single-quoted (verbatim) strings and escape single quotes inside them:

```
puts 'sed \'\#/,#d\' /tmp/dest_sorted'
#> sed '\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted
```

Comment: I don't get what you get. I get ```"sed '\\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"```

Comment: How did  you get it? How do you want to execute this command?

Comment: @KenJenney You're getting `"sed '\\#/,#d' /tmp/dest_sorted"` because you're using `p`, which calls `inspect` on its arguments. @mrzasa is using `puts`.

Comment: @JordanRunning that was it. I was using p. Thanks!

Comment: @JordanRunning that was it. I was using p. Thanks!